# CSS Menu Problem

Tags: html, css, cascadingdropdown, drop-down-menu

I have this CSS Menu. It's fully functional.

[image]

But when I put it in my page inside some table cell, it blows up like this. Don't mind the silver and the blue lines, they are from the page.

[image]

Now I have debugged the page and the menu itself. No error still this weird behavior. Then I got another menu and put that in here and it showed the same error. Any idea why is this happening?

I could paste the code but I don't think anybody is going to go through 500 lines of HTML and 100 lines of CSS.

I am using the latest Firefox. IE6 shows the same behavior.

**check the code here...**

[CSS Menu Independent in a page](http://jsfiddle.net/ne4Mv/)

[CSS Menu Inside a complex page](http://jsfiddle.net/5n4Vr/1/)

Comment: How about posting a live demo somewhere? http://jsbin.com and http://jsfiddle.net are both good. Don't post the *entire* page, just the minimal snippet to demonstrate the problem, presumably the menu within a `td` and one outside to show the comparison.

Comment: You will probably need to post some code. But for what it's worth, this looks like different CSS rules applying inside the table than without. The right tool to find out which rules apply is Firebug's right-click "Inspect Element" function.

Comment: It's very difficult without the code, anyway using Tables in HTML/CSS are so outdated.

Comment: @Charlie Sheen, except for tabular data. Tables *do* serve a valid purpose...

Comment: @ricebow: True and correct, but for his purpose it's not needed. :)

Comment: @Charlie Sheen, on that point I agree with you, yes.

Comment: the menu the cell of a complex table
http://jsfiddle.net/5n4Vr/1/

Comment: the menu very independent

http://jsfiddle.net/ne4Mv/

Comment: if you can post code , i will make it working and post it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "in-place" stylesheet is much longer than your "minimum" one, and contains rules that are changing the layout. In particular, do a search for "280" -- you're setting some widths to that.

Comment: @dragosplesca what did you do.. now the alignment is fine but the dropdowns are fine only on jsFiddle.. they aren't working on my system

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, tables get some default styles that are not what you expect. I can't recall right now, but I think one of them was align="centre" by default.

Maybe try setting the table attributes to what you want them to be explicitly?

W3Schools for [table attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp).